# Internal state in backbonejs application

Tags: rest, web-applications, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-routing

I am creating an application and trying to figure out best way to deal with navigation in it. User can choose different view settings (which content to show and options to filter it). Part of settings is stored in backend in user preferences model. Another part is stored in url and managed by router. But there is more settings I want to keep. The reason: I want to be able to refresh content therefore I need to keep settings somewhere, not update content on user actions and forget how I came to this state. My question is: what is the best place for such settings? Collection object? View object? My own controller?

P.S. to make it more clear, I'm working on rss reader application. And I want, for example, to show last week posts from certain feeds which are starred etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save it in the URL. Thats the only place you can really rely on. If you need more then routes use query parameter like in a classic web application and use them in the view.